# How to check "a in a certain cell"? in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask questions about excel. 
I just want to create an IF function in excel, and I want to test whether a certain cell contains "$."

For example, I want to say: =IF("$" is in cell $B$3, True, False).

I'm not used to excel, and was wondering if there is like "in" function for excel. 
Thank you.

---

Edit: Sorry, the question wasn't clear. Can I test for the currency of a certain cell? i.e. IF B12's currency is USD, return X.

Comment: Are the cells formatted as currency or are the cells text that look like currency? as in when you click on the cell does the `$` show up in the formula bar?

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for the reply. It is set as currency. I guess my question is different then. Can I test IF currency = $? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(CELL("format",B3)="C2","True","False")
```

You may need to test the cells in question to ensure that `CELL("format",B3)` returns `C2` for you local settings, and change the test accordingly.

[image]

Comment: `=CELL("format",B3)="C2"` to get a true boolean value.

Comment: Hi, where does the C2 value come from? I don't see anything in the screenshot?

Comment: C2 is not the C2 cell on the worksheet. It is an abbreviation for **Currency 2**, one of the standard currency formats on a EN-US regional system.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Google Spreadsheet. I'm not sure if the format value works the same in Google Spreadsheet. I'm getting #Value! error saying "Function CELL parameter 1 value is format."

Comment: You asked for Excel not Google Spread Sheet.  You got an answer for Excel not Google Spread Sheet.  Though many functions are the same, there are more differences than similarities. @Vinci

Comment: @Vinci in Google sheets use John Twedt's answer.  Next time tell us what you are using, they are not the same.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. I will mention Google Spread Sheet next time!

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",$B$3))
```

The "SEARCH("$",$B$3)" part will return an integer location for the "$" in the cell, or #VALUE! if it doesn't find it.

The "=ISNUMBER()" part just checks if SEARCH gave it a number or not.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This would work if the number was text with the `$` sign, but the OP has clarified that the `$` comes from formatting, so the cell does not actually contain `$` it is merely a number that has been formatted to show the number in USD format.

Comment: Though this will work in Google sheets, which apparently is what the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

Just use IF

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

```
=IF(B3="$", "True", "False")
```

Comment: the B column variables are mixed up with digits, i.e. $5, $10. If I do it your way, when B3=$5, the statement will return false?

Comment: OK, I thought 'contains' meant solely.